# How to create a zip then rename with shell?

Tags: bash, shell, osx-mavericks, automator

I've been trying to figure out how to do this with Mac OSX Automator, and have got to the point where I can create the individual zip files with a shell script, but I can't work out how to rename the zip files I've created automatically.

I'm trying to:

1. Zip a bunch of .mp3s in a folder as individual zip files (successfully done this part)
2. Prepend 'ibm-' to those zip files and make the whole filename 'websafe' i.e. remove spaces, convert underscores to hyphens and all uppercase letters to lowercase

Here's the shell script I have so far, I just need to work out how to do point 2 to the resulting zip files and am a bit lost!

**Shell script**

```
for f in "$@" 
do 
    zip -j "$f.zip" "$f"
done
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Osu

Comment: Do you get much compression by zipping an mp3? I don't expect that the audio file will have much redundancy to justify a compression.

Comment: I think spaces and underscores are perfectly websafe. Do you mean newsgroup-safe perhaps.

Comment: Hi both, it's not for compression reasons, the site these are going on need to be uploaded as zip files - Rembunator, spaces on linux systems can cause problems I'm told hence why I'm trying to minimise potential problems

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
for f in "$@" 
do 
    n=$(echo "$f"|sed "s/ //"|sed "s/_/-/"|awk '{print tolower($0)}')
    zip -j "ibm-$n.zip" "$f"
done
```

With sed you can replace characters in a string. You might want to google it. It's definitely worth it.

Comment: Thanks for this - running it in Automator says there's an error...any ideas? It's not telling me what's wrong exactly either...